# Parsing JSON: multi-level array

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing, indexing

I need to get an item from the json output however the json contents aren't always consistent.

For example if I wanted get the value for "name" it would be `['result']['attributes'][0]['name'];`

But in the event that the json is delivered as the second example it would be `['result']['attributes'][1]['name'];`

```
{"result":{
    "attributes":[
        {"user":"newb","name":"mike"},
        {"state":"california","city":"los angeles"}
    ]
}}

{"result":{
    "attributes":[
        {"state":"california","city":"los angeles"},
        {"user":"newb","name":"mike"}
    ]
}}
```

How would I get the "name" value if the index of the array it's in is unknown?

Comment: Do you have any control over the JSON output?

Comment: I do not, it's an output from an 3rd party api.

Comment: That's unfortunate. I would at least file a bug report with the 3rd party, as the `attributes` property is not designed very well; instead of an array of bizarrely-grouped attributes, it should just be an object with each attribute declared separately. i.e.: `{"result":{"attributes":{"user":"newb","name":"mike","state":"california","city":"los angeles"}}}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return the index into the `attributes` array that contains the object with a `name` attribute of `"mike"`.

```
function extractNameFromJson($json) {
    foreach ($json->result->attributes as $i => $attribute) {
        if (isset($attribute['name']) && $attribute['name'] == 'mike') {
            return $i;
        }
    }
}

$index = extractNameFromJson($json);
echo $json->result->attributes[$index]['user'];

==> newb
```

Comment: I need the index of the attribute mike would be in. I am trying to write a function where I can get the value of user where name = mike. That way in the event both attributes contained the same user but different names.

Comment: @MikeMills - Is this what you meant?

Comment: It's a bit closer to what I need. Lets say in the json there is a key in the attributes called "fieldid" and the value of that is "372", and in every attribute there is a key called "value" and I need to get the value of the "value" key where fieldid == 372.

Comment: something like: function getfieldid($json, [fieldid value]){ $djson = json_decode($json, true); //code to find value of key "value" where key "fieldid" == [fieldid value] }

Comment: function Getfieldid($json, $fid) { $djson = json_decode($json, true); foreach ($djson['result']['attributes'] as $i => $attribute) { if (isset($attribute['fieldId']) && $attribute['fieldId'] == $fid) { return $djson['result']['attributes'][$i]['value']; } } } It's working now, thanks David :)

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = obj.result.attributes;
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++)
    if ("name" in arr[i])
         return arr[i].name;
```

or, if it's always only the two objects in the array:

```
 var attrs = obj.result.attributes;
 return attrs["name" in attrs[0] ? 0 : 1].name;
```

But I would insist on a change in that api, the two objects should be just merged.

---

EDIT: Sorry, here comes the PHP:

```
$attrs = json_decode($jsonStr, true)["result"]["attributes"];
return $attrs[ isset($attrs[0]["name"]) ? 0 : 1 ];
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants a PHP solution--not Javascript.

Comment: Uh, why do I always think "JavaScript" when it's highlighted as "JSON"? :-(

Comment: Yes, I'm developing in PHP. Sorry for any confusion.